Public CVAT local server to the Internet
I want to public my CVAT local server to the Internet. However, the result always "This site can’t be reached  took too long to respond." I don't know what I've missed. Is there any thing I have to take into consideration with the "CVAT_HOST" labels in Traefik? Thanks for your attention and support.
First, I configured Traefik to listen from 0.0.0.0:8080. Then I also forward port 8080 of my local machine to the port 8000 in the Internet. Finally I used my public IP from https://www.whatismyip.com/ with port 8000 to access my local server.

Did you follow a guide? A link to it could be helpful

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
